# Nullify object passed to a function

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, pass-by-reference

I have the following problem with objects in actionscript3:

```
var o:Object = new Object();
destroyObject(o);
trace(o); // [object Object]

function destroyObject(obj:Object):void{
   obj = null; 
   trace(obj); // null
}
```

Since objects are passed by reference in AS3 I assume that the previous code would change `o` to `null`, but it doesn't. 
Could someone explain me 'why'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are passed by reference, but the reference itself is passed by value. The statement `obj = null` sets the parameter `obj` to null, which means that `obj` no longer references the object, but the object itself is still present, and is still referenced by the variable `o` when `destroyObject` returns.

Comment: thanks, so, in other words, I can't make it work inside the function, it has to be outside?

Comment: correct. the object will be released when all references to it are removed, so you'd have to remove the "o" reference first.

Comment: I think it is called "passed by value", same as in Java.

Comment: @negative. You're right. Though ,sadly, the actionscript documentation insisst on saying that actionscript is pass-by-ref, so this confuses a lot of people.